# How much distance use second router via LAN?

Tags: ethernet

I am using a broadband connection with WiFi router in my office, I want to connect another TP Link router via lan cable, but our house is 80 meter distance.

Is this distance is okay or not okay?

Comment: *research* "what is the maximum length for ethernet cable"

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the cabling - this is within spec for gigabit ethernet - total run should be <= 100 meters - 90 meters **solid core** + <= 10 meters stranded core for the leads the end.

I think (but am not certain) the maximum size for stranded cable is 15-39 meters depending on the thickness of copper - you can go longer then that but it will be "out of spec" and performance is not guaranteed.

You could, of-course, use fibre cable.